# Agent behind firewall needs to POST data to external tool via proxy

Tags: proxy

I have what may be a simple request. I have vendor APM agent that sits on our network and can only access the public internet via a proxy in the DMZ we've set up.

The issue is that I'm looking to post data from this agent to a 3rd party alerting tool. The fields on the agent only allow for a hostname and port to be entered. I can't enter the tool's hostname because it's not whitelisted on our network.

If I enter the proxy's hostname/port instead of the tool's - can the proxy forward out the request for me, or do I need to know the final destination's hostname in my initial request for the proxy to do it's job? Basically can I treat the proxy as my final destination and let the proxy do the rest, or do I need to embed that information into my initial request?

[Request Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0QRX.png)

Thank you,
M

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can always have a "legal man in the middle" (a.k.a. proxy).

If the tool that you are using doesn't give you the ability to enter both, a proxy and a destination, then the easiest is indeed to install a server on a computer which has Internet access to the 3rd party and redirect HTTP requests as required.

You do not say which server(s) you're using. [Nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) is pretty good to implement proxy services. It has many options just for that. [Apache2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) is more complicated, to my point of view, but it can also do it for you.

The fact that it is a `POST` should make no difference. I'd suggest you properly document your work so people coming behind you (including yourself!) will understand what that specific entry is about and how to test that it still functions. Especially in your case where the proxy is to be used to warn you about problems. If that fails, you may feel like there are no problems, which would not be the case...